# How to round an array of numbers to 3 digits in java

Tags: java, rounding, out-of-memory

I am trying to round an array of numbers to three decimal places in java, the reason being that I am running into an OutOfMemoryError (array is exceeding the VM's limit).  I was curious if there was a way to do this without writing an entire new method or anything drastic like that.

EDIT: here is all the code

```
public class GuitarHero {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int index = 0;
    double sample = 0.0;
    String keyboard ="1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm,";

    GuitarString[] string = new GuitarString[keyboard.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        double concert = 110.0 * Math.pow(2,i-24);
        string[i] = new GuitarString(concert);
    }

    while (true){

        if (StdDraw.hasNextKeyTyped()) {
            char key = StdDraw.nextKeyTyped();
            index = keyboard.indexOf(key);

            if (index >= 0 && index < 37){
                string[index].pluck();
            }
            //sample = string[index].sample() + string[index+1].sample();
            //StdAudio.play(sample);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<37; i++){
            sample = string[i].sample();

            StdAudio.play(sample);
        }

            for(int i = 0; i < 37; i++){
                    string[i].tic();
            }           
        }   

    }
}
```

end of code 1

```
public class GuitarString {

    private RingBuffer buffer; // ring buffer
    // YOUR OTHER INSTANCE VARIABLES HERE
    private int ticTimes = 0;
    // create a guitar string of the given frequency
    public GuitarString(double frequency) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    int N;
    N = (int)(44100/frequency);
    buffer = new RingBuffer(N);
    for (int i=1; i <=N; i++ ){
       buffer.enqueue(0.0);        
        }
    }

    // create a guitar string whose size and initial values are given by the array
    public GuitarString(double[] init) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    buffer = new RingBuffer(init.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < init.length; i++){
        buffer.enqueue(init[i]);
        }
    }

    // pluck the guitar string by setting the buffer to white noise
    public void pluck() {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        while(!buffer.isEmpty()) buffer.dequeue();
    while(!buffer.isFull()){
    buffer.enqueue(Math.random()-0.5);
}
}

    // advance the simulation one time step
    public void tic() {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    double value1, value2;
    value1 = buffer.dequeue();
    value2 = buffer.peek();
        buffer.enqueue(((value1+value2)/2)*0.996);
    ticTimes++;
    }

    // return the current sample
    public double sample() {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    return buffer.peek();
    }

    // return number of times tic was called
    public int time() {
        // YOUR CODE HERE

    return ticTimes;
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      double[] samples = { .2, .4, .5, .3, -.2, .4, .3, .0, -.1, -.3 };  
      GuitarString testString = new GuitarString(samples);
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          int t = testString.time();
          double sample = testString.sample();
          System.out.printf("%6d %8.4f\n", t, sample);
          testString.tic();
      }
  }

}
```

end of code 2

```
public class RingBuffer {
private int first;            // index of first item in buffer
private int last;             // index of last item in buffer
private int size;             // current number of items of buffer
private double[] buffer;

// create an empty buffer, with given max capacity
public RingBuffer(int capacity) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    buffer = new double[capacity];
    first =0;
    last  =capacity-1;
    size  =0;
}

// return number of items currently in the buffer
public int size() {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    return size;
}

// is the buffer empty (size equals zero)?
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    if (size == 0) 
    return true;
    else 
    return false;
}

// is the buffer full (size equals array capacity)?
public boolean isFull() {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    if (size == buffer.length)
    return true;  
    else
    return false;

}

// add item x to the end
public void enqueue(double x) {
    if (isFull()) { throw new RuntimeException("Ring buffer overflow"); }
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    last = (last+1)%buffer.length;
    buffer[last]=x;
    size++;
}

// delete and return item from the front
public double dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) { throw new RuntimeException("Ring buffer underflow"); }
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    double temp = buffer[first];
    first = (first+1)% buffer.length;
    size--;
    return temp;
}

// return (but do not delete) item from the front
public double peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) { throw new RuntimeException("Ring buffer underflow"); }
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    return buffer[first];
}

// a simple test of the constructor and methods in RingBuffer
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    RingBuffer buffer = new RingBuffer(N);
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    buffer.enqueue(i);
    }
    double t = buffer.dequeue();
    buffer.enqueue(t);
    System.out.println("Size after wrap-around is " + buffer.size);
    while (buffer.size() >= 2) {
    double x = buffer.dequeue();
    double y = buffer.dequeue();
    buffer.enqueue(x + y);
    }
    System.out.println(buffer.peek());
}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Rounding ? OOM error ? Drastic method implementation required ?

Comment: Rounding a double won't cause it to use less memory.

Comment: Man, your problem clearly don't come from the possible rounding of a double, but rather from what's inside your GuitarString class (**if** your application code is reduced to what you show us).

Comment: can you show the code, which is causing OOM error?

Comment: yep, one second, but the issue is that there are 3 classes involved in total, so it is a bit much

Comment: what is the string[] array? what do you do in the GuitarString class?

Comment: Yep, you're *way* off target here in the problem and its solution. You probably should delete this question and first do some debugging to find the error since there can be no possible solution until this is found.

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: your code looks like you try to calculate frequencies. i guess you want to start with the frequency 110 Hz, which is the A which is 3 octaves below the standard 440 Hz. However, Math.pow(2, i-24), for i=0, is Math.pow(2, -24), which is something near 1/(16 million). this is probably not a frequency you are interested in. most likely, instead of the "i-24", you need some fraction there like "i/24" or i divided by 12.

Comment: yep, no intrest in some absurd frequency like that, but that is how our teacher told us to calculate the frequency, so that is how it was calculated.

Comment: one quick thing, I did follow the stack trace and it appears that the issue originates from the 

    string[i] = new GuitarString(concert); line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in the first iteration of that loop the code is trying to allocate an array of  1,681,534,603 doubles (44100 / (110 * 2^-22)), which would require about 3GB of memory. I suggest you find a different solution.

Comment: haha, wow I did not realize it was taking so much memory, when I ran it at home everything ran smoothly, i didn't think that it was taking so much RAM, thanks man, ill think up another solution.

Comment: how did you calculate that by the way, for future reference?

Comment: A primitive double in Java is two bytes, and a gigabyte is 1024*1024*1024 bytes.